# rsync on a webdav folder doesn't work

Tags: rsync, webdav

I tried to sync pdf files of a local folder on my PC on a webdav folder (box account). I mounted that folder with : `davs://dav.box.com/dav`. I am on ubuntu 14.04

```
rsync -avu --include="*/" --include="*.pdf" --exclude="*" L2/ /run/user/1000/gvfs/dav:host=dav.box.com,ssl=true/dav/Cours/
```

The above rsync command created on the webdav folder the directory tree but it does not copy any file.

I got plenty of :

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/run/user/1000/gvfs/dav:host=dav.box.com,ssl=true/dav/Cours/SymCristalline": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: failed to set times on "/run/user/1000/gvfs/dav:host=dav.box.com,ssl=true/dav/Cours/SymCristalline/Cours": Operation not supported (95)
...
```

Then I got the list of files I want to sync.

```
SymCristalline/
SymCristalline/TD_2013.pdf
SymCristalline/blanche.pdf
SymCristalline/inter_tables_of_crist__vol_a.pdf
SymCristalline/inter_tables_of_crist__vol_d.pdf
....
```

Then I got plenty of

```
rsync: mkstemp "/run/user/1000/gvfs/dav:host=dav.box.com,ssl=true/dav/Cours/SymCristalline/.TD_2013.pdf.tgEY8n" failed: Operation not supported (95)
rsync: mkstemp "/run/user/1000/gvfs/dav:host=dav.box.com,ssl=true/dav/Cours/SymCristalline/.blanche.pdf.tZ2XyK" failed: Operation not supported (95)
....
```

and finaly :

```
sent 93,577,889 bytes  received 38,505 bytes  20,577.29 bytes/sec
total size is 93,541,542  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]
```

At the end, on the webdav folder, there is all directories but not any files.

Comment: Maybe the issue comes from permissions. If I remove all options which preserve permissions it works. Thus `-a` comes `-rl`

Answer (score 6):

It's likely this is due to archive mode (`-a`) as WebDAV protocol does not support updating file permissions.

Comment: Removing this option fixed the same error in my environment; I believe this should be marked as the answer.